# SVN over HTTPS broken after 12.04LTS upgrade to 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, svn, apache2.4

I just upgraded from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS.  Up until the upgrade, I was running Subversion over Apache 2.2 without any issues.

After the upgrade I get Access Forbidden messages when connecting from TortoiseSVN and I don't get any error message, just a blank screen, when connecting straight from HTTPS via a browser. It accepts my login though, but I don't have access to the repos.

Here is a sample of the error log when trying to connect to the 'Gravity' repository on my server:

```
[Tue May 26 09:03:02.244883 2015] [authz_svn:error] [pid 32362] [client 172.31.40.252:24361] Failed to load the mod_authz_svn config: Section name 'Gravity:' contains non-canonical fspath ''
[Tue May 26 09:03:02.244910 2015] [authz_svn:error] [pid 32362] [client 172.31.40.252:24361] Access denied: 'ccampbell' GET Gravity:/user
```

Here is a sample of the accessfile (located at /etc/apache/svn_accessfile)

```
[groups]
gravity_users = ccampbell
[Gravity:/]
@gravity_users = rw
```

Here is the complete apache configuration (000-default.conf), I replaced actual server names with "example.com"

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin help@example.com
        ServerName db.example.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/db_example_com_cert.cer
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

# Begin Subversion Repositories through https
<Location /Gravity>
     DAV svn
     SVNPath /svn/Gravity
     SSLRequireSSL
     AuthzSVNAccessfile /etc/apache2/svn_accessfile
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Gravity subversion repository"
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn_passwdfile
#     <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
#     </LimitExcept>
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Apparently a trailing slash causes this: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201405.mbox/%3C20140520091610.GA11975@ted.stsp.name%3E, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580771/subversion-upgrade-from-1-7-4-to-1-8-11-issue-with-mod-authz-svn - though how one would handle a trailing slash when the path is just a `/` is a mystery.

Comment: @muru Yes, I saw that on stackoverflow earlier this morning.  I have also tried different syntax with SVNParentPath as well as AuthzSVNAccessFile and 'Satisfy all' with no success.  I just left the original configuration in the post for clarity sake.